# Data Recall and Input Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I am working on creating a website that will recall data from a spreadsheet (looking at using Google Spreadsheets or SQLite) in a similar form as to the stock exchange except I would like the "stock" and "prices" to be pulled from the spreadsheet which can be live updated.

I have asked on Reddit, searched through the google help guides, but couldn't find the right resource.  I was told that running it through GitHub would be an option.  Any help would be appreciated.

For a reference of what I would like to do, I would like to make a site similar to this one: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/live/charts

Only hopefully much cleaner and only with the chart + filtering allowed.  Then the person using the site would be able to select the "company" to see that "company's" "stock" and "history" that is all managed via a database that I manage.

I can do all of this in Excel but I would like to make a secure sharing platform online.

Thank you for your time and help.  If there is an order in which to learn these things or do these things, please let me know.

Have a great day.